# Read multiple csv files into a single dataframe and rename columns based on file of origin - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have around 100 csv files with each one containing the same three columns. There are several ways to read the files into a single dataframe, but is there a way that I could append the file name to the column names in order to keep track of the origin of the columns?

I have now tried to import the files using the following code:

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd   

df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "my_files*.csv"))))
```

For example, if the inital files are:

"A_reduced.csv" and "B_increased.csv"
and each file contains three columns (Time, X, Y)

The expected output would be:

| Time | X_A_reduced | X_B_increased | Y_A_reduced | Y_B_increased |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 42 |  |  |  |

Comment: Could you give an expected output?

Comment: I have now editted my post to include this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You coud add a [prefix](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) (or [suffix](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html)) to the column names prior to concatenating the dataframes, eg:

```
def f(i):
    return pd.read_csv(i).add_prefix(i.split('_')[0] + '_')

df = pd.concat(map(f, glob.glob(os.path.join('', "my_files*.csv")))
```